# Como decidir entre vírgula e ponto e vírgula?

Tags: português-brasileiro, pontuação, vírgula

Como saber quando utilizar esses sinais de pontuação?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse artigo tem uma boa explicação sobre o uso dos dois tipos de pontuação. Concordo que atualmente, são raras as situações que usamos o ponto e virgula.

Segue o texto:

> Veja a diferença entre os dois recursos
>
> Já aconteceu de você escrever um texto e ficar em dúvida se deveria
>   ter uma vírgula ou um ponto e vírgula? As duas pontuações devem ser
>   usadas em momentos diferentes.
>
> “O ponto e vírgula muitas vezes é ignorado, as pessoas não têm mais o
>   hábito de utilizá-lo. Já a vírgula é imprescindível”, afirma a
>   professora Priscila Câmara, de Gramática e Interpretação de Texto.
>
> Para entender certinho quando você deve usar cada um dos recursos,
>   confira a explicação da prof. Priscila:
>
> **Vírgula**
>
> A vírgula é um recurso que ajuda na clareza e ritmo do texto. Quando
>   nós a utilizamos, a nossa entonação fica diferente, pois inserimos
>   algumas pausas.
>
> Há muitas regras de utilização de vírgula. As principais situações que
>   devemos usar são:
>
> 1. Enumeração  Ex: Eu tenho aula de português, matemática e ciências.
>
> A vírgula permitiu a separação e enumeração de cada matéria.
>
> 2. Separar vocativos  Ex: A lição que você não fez, Felipe, vale nota.
>
> Vocativo é quando a gente invoca e cita alguém. Ele deve ser sempre
>   isolado por vírgulas.
>
> 3. Separar aposto Ex: No sábado, dia que não tem aula, vou para a praia.
>
> Temos um aposto quando nós trazemos uma observação ou uma explicação
>   sobre o que foi dito anteriormente. Ele também ficará isolado por
>   vírgulas.
>
> 4. Antes de conjunções coordenativas  Ex: mas, porém, pois, contudo, entretanto, logo, então…
>
> Vamos usar a vírgula sempre que tivermos uma oração coordenada
>   aditiva, adversativa, conclusiva e etc. Existem duas exceções para
>   essa regra: a vírgula não deve anteceder as conjunções “e” e “nem”.
>
> 5. Indicar omissão de alguma palavra Ex: Carmem ficou alegre; eu, triste.
>
> Pensando apenas na vírgula da frase anterior, podemos perceber que ela
>   tem a função de substituir o termo “fiquei”.
>
> **Ponto e vírgula**
>
> Já o ponto e vírgula deve ser usado em outras situações. Pegando ainda
>   o exemplo anterior “Carmem ficou alegre; eu, triste”, nós percebemos
>   que há o paralelismo na frase. Nós usamos o ponto e a vírgula para
>   separar contrastes.
>
> Ele também vai ser utilizado em comparações. Por exemplo: “A França
>   com vinhos e perfumes; a Inglaterra com tecidos e carvão”.
>
> O terceiro caso que devemos usar o ponto e vírgula é quando temos
>   diversos tópicos e precisamos fazer a separação dos itens. Isso
>   costuma aparecer também em seminários, por exemplo.
>
> Os alunos precisarão de:
>
> lápis; borracha; caneta azul; caderno.

Fonte: [Stoodi](https://www.stoodi.com.br/blog/2017/02/24/quando-eu-devo-usar-virgula-e-o-ponto-e-virgula/)